# How to set ImageView over ImageView in GridView and BaseAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, baseadapter

Suppose I have multiple images that I want to set on top of the other, how can I do this in GridView?

Like:
Background
ImageView1
ImageView2 at bottom-right of the ImageView2

Here is an example for what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS36H.png

Here is my codes
Activity:

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;
    String Questions = Question.Questions;
    int level = Levels.level;

    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        //matrix.setSaturation(0); //0 means grayscale
        matrix.setSaturation(0);
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return ThumbIds.length;

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Questions, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(ThumbIds[position]);



        if(pref.getBoolean(level+"answered"+position, false)){

            //Thats the ImageView I want to set over the another ImageView
            /*ImageView answ;
            answ = new ImageView(mContext);
            answ.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            answ.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            answ.setImageResource(R.drawable.answered);*/

            imageView.setImageResource(ThumbIds[position]+1);
        }

        return imageView;

    }


    public static Integer[] ThumbIds =
        {
        R.drawable.1,
        R.drawable.2,
        R.drawable.3,
        R.drawable.4,
        R.drawable.5,
        R.drawable.6,
        R.drawable.7
        };  

}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/layout" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />

<GridView 
android:id="@+id/Question"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
tools:context=".Question" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Question activity I get the GridView

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml layout with two images inside relative layout. And inside getView inflate that layout, set the images. and return the inflated view.